# Shiny Action Button Not working from module

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I have defined my action button from a module as shown bellow.

Now it cannot trigger an observe event when pressed.I had this thinking that modules are isolated and self sufficient but seems not .Putting this in my server it works well but i do not want to clutter my server.

Any Idea?

```
cool_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
  uiOutput(ns("myUi"))
  )
}

cool <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$butonid,{
    print("Button from Module")
  })

  output$myUi <- renderUI({
    tabsetPanel(

      tabPanel(title = "sometitle",actionButton("butonid","My Button"))
    )
  })
}

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  cool_UI("myUi")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(cool,"myUi")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to namespace the ID of the button you create in your module server function.

```
cool <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns

  observeEvent(input$butonid,{
    print("Button from Module")
  })

  output$myUi <- renderUI({
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(title = "sometitle",actionButton(ns("butonid"),"My Button"))
    )
  })
}
```

Note the inclusion of `ns <- session$ns` at the top of the module server function.

`input` is namespaced in the module server function, but text strings used as widget IDs aren't.